# jQuery position of elements on load

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using jQuery to apply some CSS rules to place several objects on my page.
However first the page is loaded, and then the css rules are done.

Thus you see the page with the elements wrong positioned, and after that everything moves to it's correct place.

Is there any way to fix that?

Example: http://mactua.eu/mactua3/index.php?language=nl (check the buttons)

P.S. I know that my jquery code is a mess, but I don't give a lot about it...

Comment: Please post the **relevant** HTML and Script code in to your question and if possible **additionally** a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsFiddle.net) demonstrating the issue. The problem with linking pages without showing code  is that ones the link is dead or the site is down your question will have no context and is of no use to future users looking for a solution for similar issues.

Comment: Works here correctly.

Comment: @MathiasB You should rewrite your question before someone closes it. Make a jsFiddle and explain your problem more detailed. Even if your question has been anwesered yet. It will help flolks with the same problem.

Comment: Maybe that can be helpful, but does it matter? Problem: jquery loads after css. Solution: hide the object and make it appear after the styling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `display:none` to the CSS of the class `more_button_container`. Then at the end of your jquery code, you can use:

```
$('.more_button_container').show()
```

Comment: Thanks, this will do what i want!

Answer (score 0):

Put:

```
body { visibility: hidden; }
```

in your CSS file. Then have your jQuery code reposition everything and do:

```
$("body").css("visibility", "visible");
```

Comment: Also a good solution, but I will use the above solution...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you provide an initial CSS file which moves all elements to the first position. Imagine someone opens your website and no JavaScript is allowed. It would be a mess. And this would solve your problem.

You can place all boxes and buttons with CSS, no JavaScript is needed. If you want to center the button you will need to do something like this: [jsFiddle centered a tag](http://jsfiddle.net/maxstoyanov/h58xq/)

To center a block element you only need this CSS code

```
width: 80px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

If it's not a block element like a tags for example you will need in addition the `display: block;` rule.

Comment: That's true, in most cases. But in this case I've got a bizarre z-index issue if I position everything with CSS... So jQuery was the only easy solution here. About the no javascript issue, I've solved this with a simple alternative css which places the button relatively.